# How to make editing form?

Tags: c#, server, client

My controller (Server side):

```
// PUT: api/People/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutPerson(int id, Person person)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != person.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PersonExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

My client:

```
 private async void btnRedClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            for (int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (listView.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    clName = listView.Items[i].Text;
                    clSurname = listView.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;
                    clBirth = listView.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text;
                }

            }

            FormaRed f = new FormaRed();
            f.Person = new Person(clName, clSurname, DateTime.Parse(clBirth));

            // Person newReport = new Person() { Firstname = f.Name123.Text, Secondname = f.Surname123.Text, BirthDay = f.dateTimePicker1.Value };

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var EditClm = new Person()
                {
                    Firstname = f.Name123.Text,
                    Secondname = clSurname,
                    BirthDay = DateTime.Parse(clBirth),
                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/People", EditClm).Result;  


            }

            if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(f.Person.ToString());
            }

            Update();
        }
```

When I open the form to change the Last name, first name or date of birth, the data from the form is correctly displayed in the rows for the change. But the change itself is not written to the database People.mdf.
All my project in https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2c2a/2PkjhrYpD

But my changes do not work, can you help me?

Comment: Have you debugged it, does the object look like it is modified if you inspect? Is there an exception?

Comment: Please consider giving more detailed information. 
Describing what you have tried to eliminate possible problems:
- What was the result of your debugging
- Does the data reach the API?
- Is there an exception on the db.SaveChanges()?
- Can you verify the content of what was send to the server (in browser)
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No it have no any an exception... All work good, but my chenging do not save at the listView